# why I use mod_rewrite in .htaccess my css files can not use?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this url:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?type=item&id=656&title=mytitle
```

Kow I want rewrite this url in .htaccess to:

```
http://domain.com/item/656/mytitle
```

I used this ruls in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

It has worked but my `css` and `js` files in `index.php` not working

My css file link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using absolute filepaths for js/css? EDIT: correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't there be a '/' or a '../' in front of that files path?

Answer (score 1):

Read about RewriteCond

```
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Then...
RewriteRule ...
```

or

```
# If the uri not starts with ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file/css
# Then...
RewriteRule ...
```

Comment: The first one allow view all files (including .php files).
The second allow only to visit url that starts with file/css.
You can also combine this two rules.